# how to send a callback to a class

Tags: c++, architecture

I have a class: `market simulator` which has a method `send_order(int qty, string symbol, double price)` called by my `xyz_strategy` class which is a trading strategy being tested. When `market_simulator` receives an order it checks market prices and decided whether it can fill the order or not. It's header is something like this:

```
class market_simulator {
    std::vector<order> orders;
    static std::shared_ptr<market_simulator> instance;
    std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<instrument> > instruments;
    ...
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<market_simulator> market();
    ... 
    void send_order(int qty, std::string symbol, double price);
};
```

Problem is I need a way for `market simulator` to send back a fill report to the sender.

My first attempt was to send a pointer to the class to the market simulator. But then market simulator must include 'xyz_strategy' (and other strategies) and then it would also have access to all its methods.

My second attempt was to create a virtual super class `order_sender` which has one method called `fill_report(int qty, string symbol, double price)`. Now market simulator only knows `order_sender` and can only call its one method. But now strategy has too many super classes to implement.

How do you implement a pointer to a function in c++, such that `market_simulator` is only aware of this function and calls it when it has an execution?

edit: the function to send a pointer to would be something like:

```
 void on_execution(int quantity, std::string symbol, double price);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options with *callback* functions, 1) Function pointers and 2) Function objects (functors).

### Function Pointers

When working with pointers to functions, using a `typedef` will usually make the program more readable:

```
typedef void (*Function_Pointer)(const std::string&);
```

You can then pass a function pointer to another function:

```
void Logger(Function_Pointer output_function)
{
  output_function("Hello");
}
```

### Function Objects

A function object is a `class` or `struct` that overloads `operator()`.

```
struct Function_Object
{
  void operator()(const std::string& text)
  {
    std::cout << text << "\n";
  }
};
```

You can pass a function object, like any other object:

```
void Logger_2(Function_Object& functor)
{
  functor("Hello");
}
```

A nice attribute of function objects, is you can define abstract function objects for a family of callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a function pointer or a lambda expression to delegate your desired callback logic.

Something like;

```
void send_order(int qty, std::string symbol, double price, void (*callback));
// ...
send_order(1, "symbol", 1, []() -> void { // callback logic } )
```